# how to concatenate different column of sql and showing it in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have `SQL` table which has several columns I want to concatenate some of the columns and edit them and then show them in a `datagrid` view I am facing a problem here witch is I am retrieving data from `sql` but i can not save them in a variable too manipulate the data and then inserting it in the `datagrid` ,  I thought of putting a data in a `datagrid` and then manipulate the hidden `datagridview` data s and then insert the new variables in new `datagrid` view but is there an easier way for doing this like the one in the `php` that we could fetch the returned data in an array and then using the variables or I should go just like the way i described.

Comment: How about writing a proper select statement which does all this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the sql statement to concat the column

```
select column1+' '+column2 from table       - in SQl server 
select column1|| ' '|| column2 from table   - in Oracle 
select concat(column1, concat(' ', column2)) from table    -in Mysql
```

and use a datasource bind to bind to datagridview

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Query for fetching your data", conn);
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", p1Value); if the query need parameters to prevent sql injection.

DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    dapter.Fill(resultDst, "TableName");
}

conn.Close();

foreach(DataRow row in resultDst.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   //manuipulate the data if needed
   //row["ColumnName"] = some value;
}


//if this is winforms you need only datagrid dataSource property to be set, if you are using asp.net //you need to databind after that.

dataGridView1.DataSource = resultDst.Tables[0];
```

From your exlanation you need something like this.